# How do games package their textures in relation to image compression?

Tags: textures, compression

I know that you have to keep in mind what platform you're targeting, but it feels like you might have to have multiple sets of textures. Like let's say you're targeting desktop. How do I know what users' computers are going to support the BC1-5 and BC6 and BC7 compression? How is this done? Compressing textures takes a lot of time, are you supposed to compress in BC7, and then in case the user doesn't support keep another copy of the images in BC1, and then also keep the original uncompressed versions as a fallback?

Answer (score 0):

To find out which hardware compressed images to ship, you do some research about the graphics cards you want to support, then you pick the common denominator of compression formats to ship on those platforms.

A third party hardware survey helps picking a good oldest card to support.

Then in your minimum specifications you tell the user that they need a gpu of a version newer than the oldest that supports the hardware compression you shipped with (or even a few versions newer depending on other factors).

If you are going to ship uncompressed then ship a lower resolution texture, a card that old is not going to be running your game at ultra settings anyway.

Comment: What about selecting formats in the installer? Or compressing to an intermediate format that's relatively fast to transcode to the supported BC type? (I think I recall seeing some middleware that does this, though I'm having trouble tracking down a link to make a proper answer of it)